# AWS Spot Instance Availability Zones

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, virtual-machine, infrastructure

I'm trying to run an AWS Instance for as cheap as possible and I can see from the pricing history that in availability zone us-east-1d the current price is at $0.25 but in us-east-1a the price is $9.60.

I put in a request for $0.3 and it's saying my request is lower than the minimum fulfillment price of $9.60. There was nowhere to specify the availability zone in the request wizard but there must be a way to get it cheaper than $9.60 which is way over the on-demand price!

Am I doing it wrong somehow or is there a way to do this?

Edit: added image of wizard, where's the option to specify availability zone?

[image: Wizard]

Answer (score 2):

On step 3 you should have the option to set your availability zone preference. Default option is "No Preference".

Comment: Added image of the options I get in step 3, as you can see us-east-1d is so much cheaper! In the help files I saw the option to specify availability zones underneath "Launch group" but I don't seem to have that.

Comment: You get the option to select zone based with classic. However with VPC, your subnet is already assigned to a specific zone. It appears the only way to change that is to create a new subnet.

Answer (score 2):

Faced the same question recently, AWS spot instance wizard is not very intuitive in this regard.

My case was a default VPC, the same as is in the initial question. Therefore to "select availability zone" one needs just to select a corresponding subnet from drop down field.

The official AWS documentation states:

> **Launching Spot Instances in an Availability Zone Group**
>
> Specify an Availability Zone group in your Spot Instance request to
>   tell the Spot service to launch a set of Spot Instances in the same
>   Availability Zone. Note that the Spot service need not terminate all
>   instances in an Availability Zone group at the same time. If the Spot
>   service must terminate one of the instances in an Availability Zone
>   group, the others remain running.
>
> Note that although this option can be useful, adding this constraint
>   can lower the chances that your Spot Instance request is fulfilled.
>
> If you specify an Availability Zone group but don't specify an
>   Availability Zone in the Spot Instance request, the action taken by
>   the Spot service depends on whether you specified the EC2-Classic
>   network, a default VPC, or a nondefault VPC. For more information
>   about EC2-Classic and EC2-VPC, see Supported Platforms.
>
> **EC2-Classic**
>
> The Spot service finds the lowest-priced Availability Zone in the
>   region and launches your Spot Instances in that Availability Zone if
>   the lowest bid for the group is higher than the current Spot Price in
>   that Availability Zone. The Spot service waits until there is enough
>   capacity to launch your Spot Instances together, as long as the Spot
>   Price remains lower than the lowest bid for the group.
>
> **Default VPC**
>
> The Spot service uses the Availability Zone for the specified subnet,
>   or if you don't specify a subnet, it selects an Availability Zone and
>   its default subnet, but it might not be the lowest-priced Availability
>   Zone. If you deleted the default subnet for an Availability Zone, then
>   you must specify a different subnet.
>
> **Nondefault VPC**
>
> The Spot service uses the Availability Zone for the specified subnet.